# XCode + svn tips, tricks, etc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn

I'm curious to know your tips and tricks using XCode and Subversion. Not necessarily only focused on actions that can be done to a svn repo from xcode itself - but what things have you done to make your life easier when working with a svn managed folder that contains an xcode project? What files did you ignore? Any custom built scripts to help you?

Answer (score 1):

no one answering? ^^

I have set my build directory to another path then the project (just XCode settings) so this will not be versioned. The other thing is that I had a lot of times inconsistencies so that I had to rebuild my project folder on the server side. (you should never copy some folder to XCode with content including. If you have to than create that folder in XCode and drag and drop the files into that folder). So in fact of those inconsistencies my project folder contains the two XCode project files and a folder called SRC which includes everything else. (so I can copy it fast to the repository).

But as soon as XCode 4 appears I will switch to git ;)